# "please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8)" - How to get gdb installed with homebrew code signed?

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, gdb, homebrew

I'm under osx 10.8.4 and have installed gdb 7.5.1 with homebrew (motivation get a new gdb with  new features such as --with-python etc... )

Long story short when I run debug within a c++ Eclipse project I get :

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 46234: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 46234: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

I have followed various suggestions for code signing

- https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin
- partly http://www.noktec.be/archives/1251 with various adjusts

So I did:

1. Set up the certificate
2. Sign the gdb -> codesign -s gdb-cert /usr/local/bin/gdb

When I re-run debugging in Eclipse I get same error as above "(please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))".

If I set back the gdb to the older gdb (in the gdb preferences of Eclipse) /usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin the debugging runs as expected.

Any solutions / hints out there ?

Thx

Pelle

Comment: Is this not a "security feature" - in other words, your system is configured to only accept software that has been officially signed? If so, hopefully there is a way to turn that feature off...

Comment: ok thanks for your feedback - i understand your security feature point but my problem is then how to do the signing... there is a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050257/gdb-fails-on-mountain-lion which didn't solve it for me yet

Comment: Sorry to revive such an old thread, but I have followed dozens of tutorials with near identical instructions and I am still not getting anywhere with V12.4 (Monterey).  Is there any new required steps?

Answer (score 159):

This error occurs because OSX implements a pid access policy which requires a digital signature for binaries to access other processes pids. To enable gdb access to other processes, we must first code sign the binary. This signature depends on a particular certificate, which the user must create and register with the system.

To create a code signing certificate, open the Keychain Access application. Choose menu Keychain Access -> Certificate Assistant -> Create a Certificate…

Choose a name for the certificate (e.g., gdb-cert), set Identity Type to Self Signed Root, set Certificate Type to Code Signing and select the Let me override defaults. Click several times on Continue until you get to the Specify a Location For The Certificate screen, then set Keychain to System.

Double click on the certificate, open Trust section, and set Code Signing to Always Trust. Exit Keychain Access application.

Restart the taskgated service, and sign the binary.

```
$ sudo killall taskgated
$ codesign -fs gdb-cert "$(which gdb)"
```

source http://andresabino.com/2015/04/14/codesign-gdb-on-mac-os-x-yosemite-10-10-2/

On macOS 10.12 (Sierra) and later, you must also

Use gdb 7.12.1 or later
Additionally prevent gdb from using a shell to start the program to be debugged. You can use the following command for this inside gdb:

```
set startup-with-shell off
```

You can also put this last command in a file called .gdbinit in your home directory, in which case it will be applied automatically every time you start gdb

```
echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit
```

SOURCE:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: As the OP pointed out, this didn't do the trick for him (and for me neither).

Comment: It seems it does not work on `macOS Sierra` with self signed certificates.

Comment: `sudo killall taskgated` is the key to solve my problem

Comment: I followed the steps precisely, and this worked beautifully for me on macOS Sierra.

Comment: @zplizzi Check out these: https://gist.github.com/hlissner/898b7dfc0a3b63824a70e15cd0180154 and these: https://gist.github.com/gravitylow/fb595186ce6068537a6e9da6d8b5b96d for setting users and groups

Comment: @vaughan Check out these: gist.github.com/hlissner/898b7dfc0a3b63824a70e15cd0180154 and these: gist.github.com/gravitylow/fb595186ce6068537a6e9da6d8b5b96d for setting users and groups

Comment: Instead of `set startup-with-shell off` you can also install the brew version of bash (`brew install bash`) and set the shell to the new bash. This can be done system wide, but simple `export SHELL=$(which bash)` suffices before calling gdb. Then gdb will safely debug through brew bash, which can be useful for passing complex arguments to the program being debugged. Turning the shell off, for example, breaks the Eclipse integration with gdb. I also had to downgrade gdb to 8.0.1 since 8.1 seems to be broken.

Comment: Performing all the steps in section 1 of https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin resolved the issue for me on macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.4).

Comment: This answer is now out-of-date for newer versions of macOS; you have to also create gdb-entitlement.xml and run codesign with --entitlements gdb-entitlement.xml. Could you please update this answer with the message "Additional steps are required on macOS 10.14 and later, see https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin" or copy the additional information about gdb-entitlement.xml from that page into this answer?

Comment: Using this answer in conjunction with Johnny's got it going again

Comment: If you are using bigSur, do https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin as @KerrickStaley says

Comment: I missed the hidden comments and wasted lots of time. @KerrickStaley 's comment should get more upvotes.

Answer (score 76):

I upgraded to `gdb 8.3` and was not able to make things working.
This helped me:

```
codesign --entitlements gdb.xml -fs gdb-cert /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

Where content of `gdb.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.debugger</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I found this solution here: https://timnash.co.uk/getting-gdb-to-semi-reliably-work-on-mojave-macos/

Note: Without the entitlement I was able to run `gdb` only with `sudo`.

Comment: What do you do if you get `error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.`

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Use the pipeline first of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32727069/339146

Comment: Failed after trying @maximser 's answer. Then this works for me. 
macOS 10.15.4, gdb 9.2 installed via brew.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat: You have to create the certificate first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020236/creating-certificate-to-sign-gdb-on-mac-os-x-from-bash

Comment: Looks like we need to repeat this command after every new build

Comment: +1, this works on 10.15.7.  I think you should reference the the link that is provided when you install it via homebrew, https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin.  Also maybe at the top mention  that this works with 10.15.X and that this is really an addendum to @maximser's answer?

Answer (score 32):

I experienced the same issue with GDB.
I am running under `Mac OS X 10.8.5` aka Mountain Lion.
I am using GDB version `7.7.1`.

I compiled my test program with following command:

```
g++ -o gdb-sample.out -g gdb-sample.cpp
```

If I entered the command `gdb sample.out`, I get the same cryptic error message:

```
"Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 46234: (os/kern) failure (0x5). (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))"
```

This error message however is a red herring.

The solution I found that worked for me was to simply invoke GDB using the superuser acct:

```
sudo gdb sample.out.
```

That works fine for me.

And that from that point I could run GDB example.out without using sudo.

Hope this helps and works for others. 
RSVP if it doesn't.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. I runed the command as root (with sudo) and it worked.

Comment: Same here. I followed all the steps mentioned earlier though.

Answer (score 29):

I made gdb work on OSX 10.9 without codesigning this way (described [here](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/39349#comment:6)):

1. Install gdb with macports. (may be you can skip it)
2. `sudo nano /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist`

   change option string from `-s` to `-sp` at line 22, col 27.
3. Reboot the computer.
4. Use gdb. If you installed it with mac ports then you must use `ggdb` command. Or made an alias in your config file:

`alias gdb='ggdb'`

and use 'gdb' command then.

Comment: I'd been running into this issue for a while and had found other how-tos unhelpful. This worked like a charm.

Comment: @BillDeRose, the same for me.

Comment: @nimrodm, you mean "sudo gdb"? it should be "ggdb" with macports

Comment: @klm123, I have installed using Homebrew (brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/gdb.rb). And yes, I meant "sudo gdb", of course.

Comment: Any why to not run this as `sudo` ?

Comment: Ugh. I don't want to have to run `gdb` as `sudo`. That seems like an unneeded security risk.

Comment: Not going to restart the computer.  There must be a command to restart something!

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but how does one do anything in #4? How does one "use gdb" or the ggdb command? Is this a command-line thing? What if you're using an IDE?

Comment: @user124384, it is command line thing. http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Running.html#Running

Comment: So does anyone know if this is possible with an IDE, like NetBeans?

Comment: If the restart is just to restart taskgated then you can do so by just killing it line in the answer above

Comment: @Michael try to restart taskgated service

Comment: Procmod and procview support (-p) was removed in 10.11.

Answer (score 9):

None of this worked for me and I had to go with a long run.
Here is a full list of steps I've done to get it working.

1. Create a certificate to sign the gdb.

Unfortunately, system certificate gave me `Unknown Error = -2,147,414,007` which is very helpful, so I had to go with a workaround.
`Keychain Access -> Create certificate ->`

Pick `login`, `gdb-cert`, `Code Signing`

Copy/move certificate to the System keychain (enter password)

2. Select certificate (`gdb-cert`) click `Get info` -> `Trust Always`
3. Disable `startup-with-shell`

Enter in console: `set startup-with-shell off`

Remember configuration:
`echo "set startup-with-shell off" >>~/.gdbinit`

4. Enable Root User

Go to `System Preferences` -> `Users & Groups` -> `Unlock it` -> `Login Options` -> `Network Account Server` -> `Join` -> `Unlock it` -> `Edit` (menu) -> `Enable Root User`

5. `sudo killall taskgated`
6. Finally sign gdb

`codesign -fs gdb-cert "$(which gdb)"`

7. Disable Root User (Step 4)
8. Reboot if still does not work. (if nothing else works, most likely it works already)

PS. I ended up using `lldb` because it just works ([tutorial](https://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html))

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who using Sierra 10.12.6 (and above) and Homebrew, `/usr/local/bin/gdb` is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/8.0/bin/gdb` (or whatever version, e.g. `8.0.1`).

You need to codesign both link and target:

```
codesign -fs gdb-cert /usr/local/bin/gdb
codesign -fs gdb-cert "/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/8.0/bin/gdb"
```

Or, if you have `greadlink` (installed via `brew install coreutils`):

```
codesign -fs gdb-cert $(which gdb)
codesign -fs gdb-cert $(greadlink -f $(which gdb))
```

Comment: did you try this on High Sierra?  It did not work for me on O/S: 10.13.6

Answer (score 5):

This may not be related. You can use lldb on macos instead of gdb. You don't need this hassle to install gdb.

lldb(http://lldb.llvm.org) is already installed by default in High Sierra

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me on Big Sur: https://dev.to/jasonelwood/setup-gdb-on-macos-in-2020-489k. The crucial missing step from other guides was the --entitlements gdb-entitlement.xml option for codesigning:

I am copying here the file gdb-entitlement.xml for reference in case the linked site disappears:
codesign --entitlements gdb-entitlement.xml -fs

where `<gdb-cert>` is the name of the certificate and  is the path to the gdb executable

`<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><dict><key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key><true/><key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key><true/><key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key><true/><key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key><true/><key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key><true/><key>com.apple.security.cs.debugger</key><true/><key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key><true/></dict></plist>`

Comment: On Monterey this throws an error `codesign: option requires an argument -- s`

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if the global change in the [highest voted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048346/348056) has some unintended consequences.

Rather than enabling the old Tiger convention, taskgated does allow signed code to run. So it might be better to just get a signed cert for gdb, similar to the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678528/348056).

After this I was able to `sudo` use gdb. If you need to use gdb w/o sudo then perhaps [this link will help](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-69/docs/code-signing.txt) though, disclaimer, I haven't tried it yet because using `sudo` is an ok solution for now`.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to follow this gist:
https://gist.github.com/gravitylow/fb595186ce6068537a6e9da6d8b5b96d#file-codesign_gdb-md

With trick to overcome: `unknown error = -2,147,414,007` during Certificate Creation described here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309123

**Notes:**

Path for gdb installed as `homebrew` package should be something like: `/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/9.2/bin/gdb`

And `csrutil enable --without debug` will cause a message about `requesting unsupported configuration`, like here:
https://totalfinder.binaryage.com/system-integrity-protection

**Test:**

```
○ → sw_vers -productVersion
10.13.6

○ → gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) 9.2
...
Thread 3 hit Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:14
14          data_t d = {0};
```

Answer (score -1):

gdb 8.3;

My problem is the same as the guy above,
solved by

```
codesign --entitlements gdb.xml -fs gdb-cert /usr/local/bin/gdb
```