# How to install gdb on OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, gdb, installation

How to install gdb on OSX 10.9?

I try to use macports:

```
port install gdb
Password:
...
--->  Updating database of binaries: 100.0%
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

But I don't have gdb executable:

```
$ which gdb
$
```

I  [found out](https://www.openlearning.com/u/alan.liu/blog/HowtoInstallGdb75InOsx/) that macports gdb on mac is called ggdb. So I make a link:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/ggdb /opt/local/bin/gdb

$ gdb --args ./prog -time
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /prog...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /prog -time
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 65740: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
(gdb)
```

So how to install gdb correctly on OSX 10.9?

P.S. Related questions, which doesn't help:

[How to get a "codesigned" gdb on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913818/how-to-get-a-codesigned-gdb-on-osx)

["please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8)" - How to get gdb installed with homebrew code signed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423124/please-check-gdb-is-codesigned-see-taskgated8-how-to-get-gdb-installed-w)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made it this way (described [here](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/39349#comment:6)):

1. > sudo nano /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist

   change option string from `-s` to `-sp` at line 22, col 27.
2. reboot the computer.
3. Use gdb

Comment: Btw. no need to reboot, you can simply kill `taskgated`. (you can even do it via Activity Monitor)