# How to restart the taskgated process?

Tags: macos, kill

I am trying to follow [this](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin) manual, which contains the instruction:

```
restart taskgated service by killing the current running taskgated process
```

How to do it? I am trying to find taskgated and got only some `ttys007`, but no task gated process:

```
$ ps | grep taskgated
66942 ttys007    0:00.00 grep --exclude-dir=.svn taskgated
$lsof | grep taskgated
$
```

Comment: You know you could just use MacPorts to get a working gdb?  That's what I did, and it was pretty painless.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, how to do it? I asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022230/how-to-install-gdb-on-osx-10-9 if you have an answer please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554439/gdb-missing-in-os-x-mavericks

Comment: http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`taskgated` is `root` process, therefore you need to use `sudo`.

```
$sudo lsof | grep taskgated  


taskgated   13            root  cwd       DIR                1,2       1156        2 /
taskgated   13            root  txt       REG                1,2      71520   530715 /usr/libexec/taskgated
taskgated   13            root  txt       REG                1,2      29968   706441 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConfigProfileHelper.framework/Versions/A/ConfigProfileHelper
```

Answer (score 6):

To save one step, simply execute:

```
sudo pkill taskgated
```

Since this is a process required by the kernel, it will be automatically respawned.

Comment: Doesn't work. The process is now automatically restarted.

Comment: Yes, of course. Please look at the question again. The user needs to restart `taskgated` by killing it. `taskgated` is needed by the kernel so you can not have it not running at all.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated the question & answer.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your computer also works.