# Creating certificate to sign GDB on Mac OS X from bash

Tags: macos, bash, certificate, sign

I am trying to install gdb on Mac OS X by following [link1](http://www.patosai.com/blog/post/installing-gdb-on-mac-os-x-yosemite) and [link2](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/). This process is done in four steps:

1. installing gdb using `brew install gdb`
2. creating a certificate
3. sign gdb using `codesign -s [cert-name] [your-gdb-location]`

How can I automate step 2 in a bash script?

Comment: Do you know the commands necessary for each step? Do any of the commands require manual input? Have you tried writing the script for this?

Comment: I edited my post: I am only interested in the command-line equivalent of 2 and 3. I guess I need to use openssl for this. Right?

Comment: For step 2 possibly (though other tools will also work). For step 3 I'm not sure but most likely an OS X tool of some sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my final code (based on [here](https://superuser.com/questions/73979/how-to-easily-create-a-ssl-certificate-and-configure-it-in-apache2-in-mac-os-x), [here](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/adding-new-trusted-root-certificates-to-system-keychain/) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/571910/how-to-add-extended-key-usage-string-when-generating-a-self-signed-certificate-u)):

```
cat > myconfig.cnf << EOF

[ req ]
prompt             = no
distinguished_name = my dn

[ my dn ]
# The bare minimum is probably a commonName
commonName = VENTOS
countryName = XX
localityName = Fun Land
organizationName = MyCo LLC LTD INC (d.b.a. OurCo)
organizationalUnitName = SSL Dept.
stateOrProvinceName = YY
emailAddress = ssl-admin@example.com
name = John Doe
surname = Doe
givenName = John
initials = JXD
dnQualifier = some

[ my server exts ]
keyUsage = digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = codeSigning

EOF

echo "generating the private key ..."
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:foobar -out server.key 2048

echo ""
echo "generating the CSR (certificate signing request) ..."
openssl req -new -passin pass:foobar -passout pass:foobar -key server.key -out server.csr -config myconfig.cnf -extensions 'my server exts'

echo ""
echo "generating the self-signed certificate ..."
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:foobar -days 6666 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt -extfile myconfig.cnf -extensions 'my server exts'

echo ""
echo "convert crt + RSA private key into a PKCS12 (PFX) file ..."
openssl pkcs12 -export -passin pass:foobar -passout pass:foobar -in server.crt -inkey server.key -out server.pfx

echo ""
echo "importing the certificate ..."
sudo security import server.pfx -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain -P foobar
```

Now you can see the certificate listed in System keychains:

[image]

To sign gdb

```
sudo codesign -s VENTOS "$(which gdb)"
```