# Issues with gdb code signature on OS X

Tags: macos, gdb, macports, code-signing-certificate

> Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 2546: (os/kern) failure
>   (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))

What's wrong with my **ggdb** debugger tool (gdb installed by MacPorts), It was working perfectly for months till now!

The whole problem starts just after running the following command to install some avr tools and libraries:
 `port install avrdude avarice avr-binutils avr-gcc avr-libc avr-gdb simulavr uisp git gcc5 gcc6`

It's not a How-to-sign question, it's already signed months ago, however I'll really appreciate any help suggestions.

---

You may need to have a look at those:

> which ggdb

```
/opt/local/bin/ggdb
```

> security find-identity -p codesigning

```
Policy: Code Signing
  Matching identities
  1) 4627C4FCFACC41114B956E7DAB83E83C014641BC "gdb-cert"
     1 identities found

  Valid identities only
  1) 4627C4FCFACC41114B956E7DAB83E83C014641BC "gdb-cert"
     1 valid identities found
```

> find / -name **gdb**

*I'm **not** using this.*

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/lldb/shared/stl_printers/gdb
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/include/gdb
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/gdb
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/gdb/bin/gdb
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/gdb/share/gdb
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/gdb/share/gdb/python/gdb
/opt/local/include/gdb
/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/gdb
/opt/local/share/gdb
/opt/local/share/gdb/python/gdb
/opt/local/share/glib-2.0/gdb
/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_cross_i386-mingw32-binutils/i386-mingw32-binutils/work/binutils-2.21/include/gdb
/opt/local/var/macports/software/gdb
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/gdb
```

> find / -name **ggdb**

*I'm using this.*

```
/opt/local/bin/ggdb
```

> uname -a

```
Darwin Ghoneim.local 15.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Thanks for advance for helping me figuring it out..

Comment: This might help perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20048346/499581, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32727069/499581