# Netbeans 8.2 C++ debugging on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans

I have been trying to enable debugging on NetBeans 8.2 C++ (OS X - Sierra - 10.12.5) without success.  I have tried the following:

- Using Mac Ports version of gdb with [code-signing](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin#Giving_gdb_permission_to_control_other_processes%7Cofficial):  *result:* gdb gives a standard error:

  > Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 3016: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
  >    (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
- Using Mac's /usr/bin/llvm: *result:*

  > GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return 0

Anyone have any success getting this to work?

Comment: I go this to work by giving up on mac ports and [installing gdb through homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423124/please-check-gdb-is-codesigned-see-taskgated8-how-to-get-gdb-installed-w).

Comment: try using lldb instead. It works quite well in QtCreator

Comment: I tried ... but Netbeans doesn't behave well with lldb.

Comment: you could try symlinking it