# GDB does not work

Tags: macos, gdb

In my Mac, 
GDB does not work with error

Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 34192: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))

I already made gdb-cert and did "sudo killall taskgated, codesign -s gdb-cert /usr/local/bin/gdb".

How can I fix it??

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8)" - How to get gdb installed with homebrew code signed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423124/please-check-gdb-is-codesigned-see-taskgated8-how-to-get-gdb-installed-w)

Comment: are you sure you code signed the correct gdb executable. If you installed with brew there might be more than one. You can execute "which -a gdb" to verify

Comment: when I execute"which -a gdb",  " /usr/local/bin/gdb" appears.
I think there is only one gdb in my Mac...

Comment: I use sudo gdb, so it works.... I don't know why it works...

Comment: @JKU what do you mean sudo gdb? Isn't this question for Mac OS X?